# jQuery If 2 conditions are met, then perform action

Tags: jquery

I am new to this so I'm still trying to learn. I have 2 separate jQuery scripts that I would like combined to achieve 1 output. One script sees if input fields are filled, then enabling submit button. The other sees if an option is selected, then also enabling submit button. I want these combined if both conditions are met then enable submit button. I tried "if ((a) && (b))" but must have did it wrong or fully understand the concept.

Thanks for your time!

```
$('input[name="switcher"]').click(function(){
    $('.signup_btn').prop('disabled', this.value == "" ? true : false);     
})
```

This code above checks for selected option:

```js
if (!$(this).is(".current") && !$("body").is(".home")) {

    $('.form_email, #membername, #memberpass').on('keyup', function() {
        let empty = false;

        $('.form_email, #membername, #memberpass').each(function() {
            empty = $(this).val().length == 0;
        });


        if (empty)
            $('.signup_btn').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
        else
            $('.signup_btn').attr('disabled', false);
    });
}
```

This code above checks for fields

Comment: Can you please share the HTML for the same?

Answer (score 0):

Add the same listener to both jQuery collections. When the callback runs, check to see if the switcher is empty - if not, enable the `signupBtn`. Otherwise, check to see if `.some` of the inputs are empty, and disable or enable the button appropriately:

```
const $switcher = $('input[name="switcher"]');
$switcher.on('click', validate);
const $inputs = $('.form_email, #membername, #memberpass');
$inputs.on('keyup', validate);
function validate() {
  const signupBtn = $('.signup_btn')[0];
  if (switcher[0].value !== '') {
    signupBtn.disabled = false;
    return;
  }
  const someBlank = [...$inputs].some(input => input.value === '');
  signupBtn.disabled = someBlank;
}
```

Note that your current code doesn't properly check whether all fields are filled - you reassign `empty` on every iteration, so the final value is only the result of the check of the last element (the `#memberpass`).